# Remove Youtube Video On Mobile For Faster Load Time Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, performance, html5-video, pagespeed

Is there a way to stop a Youtube Video from downloading and decreasing the load time of the page on mobile, I don't need a video in the mobile view of my page.

And the only way I found is by removing it by its CSS and that removes it physically but it doesn't help with the load time. I saw somewhere you can do it with PHP is that right?

I'm using WordPress and WPBakery

Comment: You could make it so that on mobile devices only an image is shown that has a link to the video, aka replacing the video instead of removing it entirely. If you add the relevant code of your attempt, people will be able to give you more concert help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.